# Multiple Settings File in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-settings, django-1.7

I'm trying to change my django 1.7 project to contain a settings folder with multiple settings files rather than just a single settings.py file.
I don't know how to configure the location of the static files correctly. What am I missing? My site is no longer working correctly.

dev_settings.py

```
from unipath import Path

PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)
MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.child("media")
STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_DIR.child("static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_DIR.child("static"),
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_DIR.child("templates"),
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

home.html

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<a href="{% url 'bank:bank_home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/logo-bank.png' %}" class="img-responsive navlogo" alt="My Bank"></a>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap_js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to tell Django where to find your renamed settings file? Or that you don't know how to configure Django static files? The solutions to these two problems are vastly different (and both require more information for a suitable answer).

Comment: @MattCooper I don't know how to configure the Django static files now that my settings file has moved into this new "settings" directory I created. It seems to find some of them but not all...?

Comment: I was originally trying to use `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in my template but then read about using the template tag instead. Don't know if that matters...?

Answer (score 1):

The important settings related to static files are as follows:

- `STATIC_ROOT` - defines the full path to where static files will be aggregated by the `collectstatic` management command (e.g. **/var/www/project/staticfiles/**).
- `STATIC_URL` - defines what URL Django will substitute into your templates for the path above to save you having to hard-code it (normally **/static/**)
- `STATICFILES_DIRS` - a tuple or list of file paths for Django to also aggregate files from, not associated with any particular app (by default, Django will automatically find and aggregate all the files under the `static` directory of any installed apps - see `STATICFILES_FINDERS` for more info). Note that this should NOT include the path defined by `STATIC_ROOT`; that path is for where Django copies your files to serve them.

Other setting defaults are normally fine to begin with (docs for Django 1.7 are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#static-files)). Be sure that you run `python manage.py collectstatic` before `python manage.py runserver` in order to aggregrate your static files into the location defined by `STATIC_ROOT`.

You can set the location of the project settings file by altering the following line in `manage.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my.project.base_settings")
```

Alternatively, you can pass in `--settings` when running `manage.py` if you want to use a different one (in dev, etc.):

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=my.project.dev_settings
```

Note that the dot notation used corresponds to a *.py file within the directory structure of your project, relative to `manage.py`. So the location of the file in the first example above would be at `my/project/base_settings.py`. There are some more details in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/).

Comment: my issue is that I don't have just one settings file so the location is `my/project/settings/base_settings.py` I know how to specify a particular file but can't correctly configure where to find the static files

Comment: Yes, I misinterpreted the core problem you're having. Will add more details.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to see a working Django implementation and compare to figure out what you've got wrong. 
Here's a simple Django project with multiple settings files:
https://github.com/marcofucci/cookiecutter-simple-django

(It's a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) project, which may be useful to you - if not just ignore it and look in {{ cookiecutter-repo-name }} for the actual django source code)

Also, I recommend the "Two Scoops of Django". Just picked it up a few days ago, loving it!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @samGbos I've actually been using the Two Scoops book and was following their chapter on creating multiple settings files but can't get it quite right (perhaps it's because I'm using 1.7)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why my setup is not working. But, to fix the issue for now, I created a completely new project using https://github.com/marcofucci/cookiecutter-simple-django

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is going wrong?
Did you include them in your url.py file?

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```